# Dynamic JQuery Form Submit for Multiple Forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have PHP that searches a database and then echoes an html form for each result found. These are loaded via AJAX into the main HTML page into a div on document load.

Now I want to have listeners for each of these forms submitting. They all have the same inputs. 
Each form has an incremental ID of processor (`processor1`, `processor2`, `processor3`, and so on).

So, depending on the results, it could be as little as one form or 50 forms. Is there a dynamic way of doing a form submit function rather than writing countless repetitive functions?

Comment: what do you mean by "*doing* form submit function"?

Comment: $("#processor1").on( "submit", function( event ) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
<form id="form1">
<form id="form2">
```

You can use a class selector

```
<form id="form1" class="forms">
<form id="form2" class="forms">
```

In jQuery:

```
$(function() {
 $('.forms').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); //Prevent submit
   console.log($(this)); //Current form submiting

   //Make ajax call for current form
 })
})
```

If u you need extra data for each form, you can use data atributte

```
<form id="form2" class="forms" data-myattr="myvalue">
```

And get it

```
...
$(this).data('myattr'); //myvalue
...
```

Comment: If I wanted to use input values for only the submitted form, would I do this?  $("this .inputclass").val(); instead of $("#form1 .inputclass").val();

Comment: `$(this).find('.inputclass').val()` will do.

Comment: $(this) is the current form object.
You can use $(this).find("selector") to search elements in the form.

Answer (score 0):

If using classes is (for some reason) not an option, you can also use 'starts with' [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

```
$('#processor*').submit(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    ...
});
```

Note that the above function should be called as a callback to AJAX function that loads the forms.